# Forward port from router to ubuntu cannot open while VPN is connected

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

I need some help with my network, so I'm forwarding port `80`, `443` and `22` from my router to my PC with Ubuntu, but the port cannot be opened even when the UFW status is disabled and if I connected to the VPN, it will open if the VPN is disconnected, but for some reason i need to keep my VPN connected 24/7, is there any solution?
[image: screenshot result of $ netstat -rn]

The VPN i'm using is Surfshark

My forwarding rules from the router:
[image: here]
My router is using public IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: From my own experience with business VPN, you need to make sure Split Tunnel has been enabled.

Comment: are you using WireGuard, OpenVPN, or IKEv2 for your VPN protocol? SurfShark supports all three. If there is an option in your SurfShark client to enable split tunneling or "bypass VPN for local addresses" then enable that option.